# Azure WebJob configurations return null

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I've got a webjob always returns null values when using CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting

I have values in my web.config file, the app.config file (which get renamed to myapp.exe.config, as expected during deployment) and also in the App Settings configuration for the website/webapp in the portal.

It's a continuous webjob that is trying to execute some logic in the static main method to read some settings etc, however it crashes as the values aren't expected to be null and then gets stuck in a loop trying to start up.

Here's some snippets of code... *it's not the actual code but you get the idea*.

```
static void Main()
{
    bool.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("IsValueTrue"));
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

The `host.RunAndBlock();` method is never reached as the call for the value `IsValueTrue` from the app.settings returns null.

Are configuration settings not available during starting of a WebJob?

Comment: I've deployed this webjob to a deployment slot only... not to the root website.

Comment: Did you add the IsValueTrue setting to the App Settings for the deployment slot?

Comment: Yep. As mentioned above, I have a web.config file for the site, a published app.config for the app and a setting in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(), use ConfigurationManager.  For example,

```
var someSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsValueTrue"];
```

The setting in the portal will take precedence over settings in your app.config and is also the recommended place to store your setting.  The code sample above should get you going.

Comment: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting() will try to get setting from the ServiceRuntime and if it failed will try get the setting from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings...